# Write CSV file from Windows Tablet to PC using C#

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2012, desktop-application

I am wondering that I want to send/write/paste **CSV** file from my Windows application running on **"Windows Tablet"** to My **Local PC**.

The condition is that I have **WIFI** connection to establish a connection from windows tablet to Local Computer. I want to send/write/paste a file to my local PC in one folder of the C drive. PC has username and password of guest account.

I have tried some few things related to remote connection, but have had no luck at all. Can you please suggest how can I do this, what will be the programming as socket or remote or any in **C# Windows Application** I need to follow where I can get the things done.

Comment: So what have you tried so far, without luck? You could also show some code, so we can see which is the unlucky piece.

Comment: I tried http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/0a7dc8/file-transfer-program-using-C-Sharp-net-windows-application/

Comment: Can you please suggest me for the remote programming in C# desktop application ?

Comment: What protocol do you intend to use? You can begin by googling HTTP/FTP C# WinForms. This can be a good start. Did you analyze the code from the link you posted? You said that you have tried it, but seems that something has gone wrong. What exactly?

Comment: I did, thanks.
I use the network sharing option for the folder, I logged into the network and write the file on the specified PC.